# Python OpenCV Aruco: Import "cv2.aruco" could not be resolved

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

`import cv2.aruco as aruco` is not importing.
I've searched online and it said to

- `pip uninstall opencv-python`

and then

- `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python`,
- `pip install opencv-contrib-python`
  the pip list results in:

[the pip list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcUk.png)

Everything successfully got installed, but the problem still remains the same.
Has anybody got any further solutions?

Comment: your system is messed up. remove everything.

Answer (score -1):

can you try pip list and paste what you get here.

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>pip list
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- --------
Adafruit-Blinka                  6.15.0
adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice 5.1.0
adafruit-circuitpython-motor     3.3.0
adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685   3.3.8
adafruit-circuitpython-register  1.9.5
adafruit-circuitpython-servokit  1.3.5
Adafruit-PlatformDetect          3.17.1
Adafruit-PureIO                  1.1.9
imutils                          0.5.4
numpy                            1.21.2
opencv-contrib-python            4.5.4.58

(will be in two comments)

Comment: pip                              21.3.1
pyftdi                           0.53.3
PyQt5                            5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5                        5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                        12.9.0
pyserial                         3.5
pyusb                            1.2.1
pyzbar                           0.1.8
setuptools                       59.1.1
Shapely                          1.8.0   (i edited the question so that the pip list picture it there)

Comment: can you try installing just opencv-python , pip install opencv-python. Remove opencv-contrib-python

Comment: @Whereismywall did it but now even just import cv2 isn't working

Comment: python version?

Comment: Python 3.9.7 64bit

Comment: can you try uninstalling opencv-python and re install opencv-contrib-python should work now

Comment: did that, cv2 returned to normal but cv2.aruco still remains unresolved..

Comment: Not sure what else can be tried, probably wait for a more experienced user